# Print the result of an Observable on button click?

Tags: f#, system.reactive

Is there anyway to print the result of a current observation from a button click?

Example:

```
button.Click.Add(fun _ ->  x |>Observable.subscribe (fun x -> printfn "%A" x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the last value the subscription has obtained in a `ref`:

```
let curX = ref None

let subscription = x |> Observable.subscribe (fun v -> 
    lock curX (fun () -> curX := Some v)
)

button.Click.Add (fun _ ->
    match lock curX (fun () -> !curX) with
    | Some v -> printfn "X yielded \"%A\"." v
    | None -> printfn "X yielded nothing."
)
```